# How to run a python program 10 times in a loop and plot the rsults in each time

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to run this code. We run the EM for 10 loops and plot the result in each loop. You want to observe the progress for each EM loop below.

```
X = np.linspace(-5,5,num=20)
X0 = X*np.random.rand(len(X))+10 # Create data cluster 1
X1 = X*np.random.rand(len(X))-10 # Create data cluster 2
X2 = X*np.random.rand(len(X)) # Create data cluster 3
X_tot = np.stack((X0,X1,X2)).flatten() # Combine the clusters to get the   random datapoints from above
class GMD:
def __init__(self,X,iterations):
    self.iterations = iterations
    self.X = X
    self.mu = None
    self.pi = None
    self.var = None

def run(self):

    self.mu = [-8,8,5]
    self.pi = [1/3,1/3,1/3]
    self.var = [5,3,1]


    for iter in range(self.iterations):
        r = np.zeros((len(X_tot),3))  

        for c,g,p in zip(range(3),[norm(loc=self.mu[0],scale=self.var[0]),
                                   norm(loc=self.mu[1],scale=self.var[1]),
                                   norm(loc=self.mu[2],scale=self.var[2])],self.pi):
                                       r[:,c] = p*g.pdf(X_tot)


        for i in range(len(r)):
            r[i] = r[i]/(np.sum(pi)*np.sum(r,axis=1)[i])

        """Plot the data"""
        fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
        ax0 = fig.add_subplot(111)
        for i in range(len(r)):
            ax0.scatter(self.X[i],0,c=np.array([r[i][0],r[i][1],r[i][2]]),s=100) 
        """Plot the gaussians"""
        for g,c in zip([norm(loc=self.mu[0],scale=self.var[0]).pdf(np.linspace(-20,20,num=60)),
                        norm(loc=self.mu[1],scale=self.var[1]).pdf(np.linspace(-20,20,num=60)),
                        norm(loc=self.mu[2],scale=self.var[2]).pdf(np.linspace(-20,20,num=60))],['r','g','b']):
            ax0.plot(np.linspace(-20,20,num=60),g,c=c)




            var_c.append((1/m_c[c])*np.dot(((np.array(r[:,c]).reshape(60,1))*(self.X.reshape(len(self.X),1)-self.mu[c])).T,(self.X.reshape(len(self.X),1)-self.mu[c])))
        plt.show()

GMD = GMD(X_tot,10)
GMD.run()
```

But after running this code it's showing this below error as a output
[this message showing when I am going to run this code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5s288.png)

Comment: code that I want to run 
https://pastebin.com/FvSadvBH

Comment: `pi` -> `self.pi`

Answer (score 0):

You could make another file and import your class and do:

```
for x in range(0,9):
    class.function()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm unable to reply to Klaus' answer but as he pointed out, you might have missed self while calling the pi value on one occasion:

```
for i in range(len(r)):
    r[i] = r[i]/(np.sum(pi)*np.sum(r,axis=1)[i]) # Here the pi should be self.pi
```